# Clarification regarding working of network layer and transport layer

Tags: networking, tcp

I have type "google.com" DNS resolves Ip address corresponding to name entered and then at transport layer it creates communication endpoints using 3 way handshake(I am considering http).and sends data in the format of  TPDU to the network layer.Now at the network layer it redirects that packet to default router which then checks network prefix and decides where to forward packet.

```
1)where the actual data is converted into packets.I mean where the packets gets generated,if answer is at the client ,then who performs this job.
2)where the address of default router is specified,how the packet gets directed from one machine to default router.
3) I know TCP receives data in the form of stream of bytes.(So I am confused between terminology of TPDU).
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps-:

1)The actual data will be converted to packets at the network layer and the job is done by the OS of the client

2)The address of the default router(default gateway) is specified on your client(in your case your pc).You can open your command prompt and type **route** **print** to check what all routes are present.The route with destination as **0.0.0.0** and **subnet mask 0.0.0.0** will be your 
default route

3)TPDU when elaborated is **transport protocol data unit**.At each and every layer of the OSI model we have a protocol data unit for example At network layer you call the data as chunk of packets,at data link layer you call it as frame and so on.For detailed information search for protocol data unit on wikipedia